# SqlConnectionStringBuilder class missing Authentication property in dotnetcore

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect to an azure SQL server with Active directory Password-based authentication. Everything works well if I use .net framework 4.7.2 Following is the code

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.Authentication = SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryPassword;
```

However, in dotnetcore `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class doesn't have the Authentication property at all! How am I supposed to make ActiveDirectoryPassword work in dotnetcore? Will this feature be coming to dotnetcore soon? What is the workaround?

Comment: Currently this is blocked on our upstream dependency on .Net Core, which does not currently have Azure AD support for SQL Client. And it will coming soon with [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is already on the Roadmap. Currently you can use the same connection string as Integrated Authentication connection string with Active Directory Interactive as value for Authentication connection property.

```
string ConnectionString =
@"Data Source=n9lxnyuzhv.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Password; Initial Catalog=testdb;  UID=bob@contoso.onmicrosoft.com; PWD=MyPassWord!";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
```

**Note:** You should use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`, or you will encounter the Exception as below

> System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.'

Comment: Tried this in .net core. But getting the error System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.'